# Silverlight ChildWindow with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am creating a custom ChildWindow that I want to use with a DataTemplate.

The DataTemplate will apply to the "body" of the window, but then, separate from that, I want to always display two buttons, "Save" and "Cancel".

I have no idea how to accomplish that...  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a copy of your ChildWindowStyle from your SdkStyles.xaml to give you a foundation for building your custom control template on. To keep a DataContext you could throw it in a UserControl as UserControl.Resources or if you're just populating ContentPresenters etc you can put the template in your own resource dictionary or wherever you like (though you might want to specify a unique x:Key name for it.) Just depends on how you'd like to use it.

Make your desired changes to the template and also add your Buttons etc. Then you can either set it as the default by replacing the Default BasedOn value in your resource dictionary to point to it or call that style explicitly.

Personally I prefer Expression Blend for all of this and there's even some tutorials out there to help you along with a Web Search (which I might suggest first next time.) Like what you might find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144194/Customizing-Silverlight-ChildWindow-Style-using-Bl)...  Hope this helps! :)